# Properties of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}$$
has the following two properties :

1. it's analytic near 0
2. it has simple poles at the integer point except 0

My attempt:

first if we can prove the series converge uniformly near the origin then its limit is automatically holomorphic,to do this using the following relationship:

$$|\sum_n\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}|\le \sum_n \frac{1}{|z^2-n^2|}\le \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}$$
hence the series converges uniformly and absolutely near 0(e.g. $|z|\le 1/2$).

For the second one, at integer $k$ the term $\frac{2z}{z^2-k^2}$ has simple pole,rest of the term has bounded sum,hence it has simple pole at $k$.

I think I haven't prove the second fact clear,it's there better proof for the second propert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $k$. For $|z-k| <\frac 1 2$ the series $\sum_{n \neq k} |\frac {2z}{z^{2}-n^{2}}|$ is dominated by $\sum_{n \neq k} \frac {2|k|+1} {n^{2}-(|k|+\frac  1 2 )^{2}}$ and hence this sum is analytic in $|z-k| <\frac 1 2$.

Comment: thank you that's what I want to claim,clear now